# О метках "Энтузиаст" и "Фанатик": предложение

Tags: предложение, знаки

Чтобы их получить, нужно 30/100 дней подряд заходиться на сайт. Вопрос о необходимости/возможности получения/накрутке не стоит. Речь немного о другом.
Почему бы не сделать более "почётные", что ли, варианты этих знаков? Например, в дополнение к "Энтузиасту" - "Ни дня без репы" (25 дней подряд получать + в репутацию. Если для тех, у кого много хороших ответов/вопросов, это не проблема, можно усложнить: 25 дней подряд получать + в репутацию за новые действия).
Или "не о том ты, Петька, думаешь"? :)

Comment: и какую цель Вы хотите достигнуть при помощи этого?

Comment: @Bald Стандартная цель: развитие ресурса. Если ты получаешь +, значит, ты полезен. А простое присутствие, в теории, можно и автоматизировать, если кто-то гонится просто за значком.

Comment: наличие/отсутствие значка ни о чем не говорит. ну это мое имхо

Comment: @Bald Вы это понимаете, я это понимаю (не тот возраст, чтобы виртуальными медальками бряцать, но (!) даже мне приятны некоторые из медалей, что я заработал). Другие мыслят иначе

Comment: Для справки: [последнее утверждение нового знака](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=%5bbadge-request%5d%20%5bstatus-completed%5d%20is%3aq) было более 5 лет назад.

Comment: @alexolut для меня тогда поясняйте: это, как вино, признак перехода в марочное? Или, как для тупого старого завлаба, признак маразма? :) Грубо говоря, система решила закоснеть?

Comment: Я к тому что надо очень постараться чтобы пропихнуть что-то новое. Система (читай как "разработчики") сопротивляется :)

Comment: @alexolut Можно вопрос вынести в чат? Или идти в стандартный? Ну, может, можно сделать громогласное объявление в стандартном чате? :)

Comment: @ViktorTomilov Мы чисто технически не сможем здесь сделать индивидульную метку для данного сайта (stackoverflow на русском). Это нужно внедрять для всей сети сайтов StackExchange. А это значит, что вам следует перевести ваше предложение на английский язык и вынести его на [главную мету](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). Но вероятность его принятия не сильно высока.